# SQL: update new column as geometric point from two columns lat, long_

Tags: sql, geospatial, latitude-longitude, alter-table

#### Background

I have a table `hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones` with following attributes:

- `lat` latitude
- `long_` longitude

#### What I tried

I am trying to create a geometry datatype column `Point` that combines `lat` and `long_`

I used the following code that I found:

```
ALTER TABLE hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
  ADD       shape Point
  ;

UPDATE  hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
  SET   shape = Point("long_", "lat")
```

#### Error I got

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function point(character varying, numeric) does not exist
LINE 4: SET     shape = Point("long_", "lat");
                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 157
```

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SO! Please **mention the blog (link)** where you got your code from! This helps us to analyze your issue. TIP: use _backticks_ (`) or **CTRL + K** to format your code. The simple quote (') doesn't work.

Comment: By the way: each question on SQL should also mention the database/[DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_management_system) used, since functions and even SQL-syntax can differ This could be done via tags, e.g. [tag:sql-server] or [tag:oracle], etc.

Comment: Seems you're using [tag:postgresql]. Did you search for the _ERROR message_ or _SQL state_? Found this [question for SQL state and point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717373/postgresql-st-geomfromtextunknown-does-not-exist).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using PostgreSQL

#### Using PostGIS extension

With extension **[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography)** installed there is the `geography` datatype for points with *latitude* and *longitude*.

To add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
  ADD COLUMN geo_point GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326);
```

To update column `geo_point` for each record (based on existing coordinates in columns `long`, `lat_`):

```
UPDATE hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
  SET geo_point = 'SRID=4326;POINT(' || long || ' ' || lat_ || ')';
```

The data value of `point` is given as text, see following example and explanation:

> 'SRID=`4326`;POINT(`-71.104 42.315`)'

- *Spatial Referencing System ID* (SRID) is specified as `4326` for [WGS 84](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) (same as used by GPS, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84))
- the geo-coordinates are specified as type POINT described by `-71.104 42.315` in exactly this order: **longitude**, followed by *space* as separator, followed by **latitude**

#### Using native data types

Without PostGIS installed, you still have the *geometric* type [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6838).
Values of this type are constructed using the geometric conversion function `point(double precision, double precision)`.

To add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
  ADD COLUMN geo_point POINT;
```

To update points for each record (based on existing coordinates in `double` typed columns `long`, `lat_`):

```
UPDATE hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
  SET geo_point = point(long, lat_);
```

This (native) geometric point can later be converted to a *geographic* point if **PostGIS** is installed and should be used.

Comment: Glad if I could help. Let me know, if the solution works (e.g. accept the answer).

Comment: I really appreciate it. This is the post that I used and did not work [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756232/moving-lat-lon-text-columns-into-a-point-type-column). Unfortunately, I still get an error with the instruction provided.
`ALTER TABLE hospitals_healthcenters_evacuationzones
  ADD COLUMN point GEOGRAPHY(POINT,26918);`
ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
LINE 2:   ADD COLUMN point GEOGRAPHY(POINT,26918);
                           ^
SQL state: 22023
Character: 72

Comment: For which reason you specified the SRS `26918` for [NAD83](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum#North_American_Datum_of_1983)? As the error states: This is not supported with type `geography` since not working with lon/lat coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ALTER TABLE hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
     ADD COLUMN shape geometry(Point,4326);

    UPDATE  hospitals_healthcenters_jointed_to_evacuationzones
      SET   shape = st_Setsrid(st_Point("long_"::double precision, "lat"::double precision),4326);
```